# Error on compilation: Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Aheadworks\Blog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface. Actual type: array; File:

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, setup-di-compile, compilation

I'm new to Magento and working on upgrading an existing project to 2.4.3. When running `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile` I'm encountering an error:

```
Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Aheadworks\Blog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface. Actual type: array; File:
```

No line number is provided. I've seen in other posts that this can be related to types not being declared in the comments, but I believe all my types are declared.  What could be going wrong?

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace X\Blog\Block\Sidebar;

use Aheadworks\Blog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Block\Sidebar\Category as AwCategory;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Model\Config;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Model\Url;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Model\Source\Category\Status as CategoryStatus;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

/**
 * Class Category
 */
class Category extends AwCategory
{
    const CURRENT_CSS_CLASS = 'current';

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param Config $config
     * @param Url $url
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        Config $config,
        Url $url,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $categoryRepository,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $config,
            $url,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Siblings categories
     *
     * @return CategoryInterface[]
     */
    public function getSiblingsCategories()
    {
        $parentCategoryId = $this->getParentCategoryId();
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(CategoryInterface::STATUS, CategoryStatus::ENABLED)
            ->addFilter(CategoryInterface::STORE_IDS, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->addFilter(CategoryInterface::PARENT_ID, $parentCategoryId)
            ->addSortOrder(
                new SortOrder(
                    [
                        SortOrder::FIELD => CategoryInterface::SORT_ORDER,
                        SortOrder::DIRECTION => SortOrder::SORT_ASC
                    ]
                )
            );
        return $this->categoryRepository->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getItems();
    }

    /**
     * Get Parent Category Id
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getParentCategoryId()
    {
        $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        return $currentCategory ? $currentCategory->getParentId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get additional css class for category item
     *
     * @param int $categoryItemIndex
     * @param int $categoryId
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalClass($categoryItemIndex, $categoryId = 0)
    {
        $cssClasses = [];
        $categoryLimit = $this->getNumCategoriesToDisplay();
        $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($categoryLimit > 0 && $categoryItemIndex > $categoryLimit) {
            $cssClasses []= self::HIDE_CSS_CLASS;
        }
        if ($categoryLimit > 0 && $categoryItemIndex == $categoryLimit) {
            $cssClasses []= self::SHADED_CSS_CLASS;
        }
        if ($categoryId && $currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $categoryId) {
            $cssClasses []= self::CURRENT_CSS_CLASS;
        }
        return implode(' ', $cssClasses);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code and let me know if it works for you

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace X\Blog\Block\Sidebar;

use Aheadworks\Blog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Block\Sidebar\Category as AwCategory;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Model\Config;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Model\Url;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Model\Source\Category\Status as CategoryStatus;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Aheadworks\Blog\Api\CategoryManagementInterface;

/**
 * Class Category
 */
class Category extends AwCategory
{
    const CURRENT_CSS_CLASS = 'current';

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param Config $config
     * @param Url $url
     * @param CategoryManagementInterface $categoryManagementInterface
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        Config $config,
        Url $url,
        CategoryManagementInterface $categoryManagementInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $categoryRepository,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $config,
            $url,
            $categoryManagementInterface,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Siblings categories
     *
     * @return CategoryInterface[]
     */
    public function getSiblingsCategories()
    {
        $parentCategoryId = $this->getParentCategoryId();
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(CategoryInterface::STATUS, CategoryStatus::ENABLED)
            ->addFilter(CategoryInterface::STORE_IDS, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->addFilter(CategoryInterface::PARENT_ID, $parentCategoryId)
            ->addSortOrder(
                new SortOrder(
                    [
                        SortOrder::FIELD => CategoryInterface::SORT_ORDER,
                        SortOrder::DIRECTION => SortOrder::SORT_ASC
                    ]
                )
            );
        return $this->categoryRepository->getList($this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create())->getItems();
    }

    /**
     * Get Parent Category Id
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getParentCategoryId()
    {
        $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        return $currentCategory ? $currentCategory->getParentId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get additional css class for category item
     *
     * @param int $categoryItemIndex
     * @param int $categoryId
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalClass($categoryItemIndex, $categoryId = 0)
    {
        $cssClasses = [];
        $categoryLimit = $this->getNumCategoriesToDisplay();
        $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($categoryLimit > 0 && $categoryItemIndex > $categoryLimit) {
            $cssClasses []= self::HIDE_CSS_CLASS;
        }
        if ($categoryLimit > 0 && $categoryItemIndex == $categoryLimit) {
            $cssClasses []= self::SHADED_CSS_CLASS;
        }
        if ($categoryId && $currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $categoryId) {
            $cssClasses []= self::CURRENT_CSS_CLASS;
        }
        return implode(' ', $cssClasses);
    }
}
```